# How to import dictionary to csv

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have to export data from dictionary to csv. Dictionary contains lists. I tried to do export like this

```r
with open("info.csv", 'w',newline='')as csvfile:
header = ['Club', 'Stadium']
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=header)
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerow(info)
```

But the result is

```r
 Club          Stadium
 ['Arsenal,    ['Emirates',
 'AFC', etc.]  'Villia park',etc.]
```

And i wanted this

```
Club         Stadium
Arsenal      Emirates
AFC          Villia park
```

How can i do it?

Comment: I'd do that with pandas. `df = pd.DataFrame(info).to_csv('a.csv', index=False)`

Comment: @TomWojcik never heard about pandas, but i'll try it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want doing it like this.

```
import csv

with open('info.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    header = info.keys()
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=header)
    writer.writeheader()
    for pivoted in zip(*info.values()):  # here we take both lists and pivot them
        writer.writerow(dict(zip(header, pivoted))) # pivoted is a 2 element tuple
```

I often use `pandas` and it's basically a oneliner with it, but it might be an overkill for your needs.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(info).to_csv('info.csv', index=False)
```

If you don't need to use `pandas` in general, better stick with built-in `csv` module.