# Looking for a way to write a dictionary to a csv in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to lookup a list of data online and I want to write the output, which is a list of dictionary to a csv file.
For instance, I want to export "results" to a CSV

```
if resp.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser")
        results = []
        for g in soup.find_all('div', class_='r'):
            anchors = g.find_all('a')
            if anchors:
                 link = anchors[0]['href']
                 title = g.find('h3').text
                 item = {
                "title": title,
                "link": link
                   }
                 results.append(item)
                 print(results)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import dictionary to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57640691/how-to-import-dictionary-to-csv)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create a DataFrame, append the results to it and export the DataFrame to a .csv file?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['title', 'link'])

if resp.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser")
    results = []
    for g in soup.find_all('div', class_='r'):
        anchors = g.find_all('a')
        if anchors:
            link = anchors[0]['href']
            title = g.find('h3').text
            df = df.append({'title' : title , 'link' : link} , ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for this.

```
my_dict = {'1': 'aaa', '2': 'bbb', '3': 'ccc'}
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    for key in my_dict.keys():
        f.write("%s,%s\n"%(key,my_dict[key]))
```

This code writes items of dictionary to csv file as this:

```
1,aaa
2,bbb
3,ccc
```

If you are trying to writing list of dictionary you should open file in 'a' format and run this for every dict on your list.